# Search box webpart display issue

Tags: sharepoint-online

When I am adding SearchBox webpart on to my page, the search box is displaying at the right side corner of the page irrespective of where the webpart is placed. Is there any solution to move the search box to the centre of the page without modifying the master page. I am using Sharepoint online

Any help/suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

IS it custom pagelayout or out of the box pagelayout, if it is custom u can use CSS to bring to center or u can still use zone index , we can provide more information if the question is more clear.

Comment: It is a custom page layout.